# Is there a practical way of creating wxPanel over another wxPanel?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

There are two main panels used for different purposes. One of the panels is used for making some drawings, using dc(Panel-D), the other one contains some buttons for getting user inputs(Panel-I). The issue is about the placement of these two panels. I am trying to place Panel-I over Panel-D as shown below(like always on top option). The difficulty in this matter, I couldn't put Panel-I in Panel-D, because we can't intervene the drawing functions on Panel-D.

I tried using different techniques with various types of wxSizers and wxSizerFlags, but couldn't get the desired orientation/placement. I would be grateful to any suggestion.

[image: Panel-I and Panel-D]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have no trouble with this if you create Panel-I as a child of Panel-D. You can then position it in any way you want: either manually (e.g. if its position is fixed), or using sizers.

Comment: I tried to achieve these panels as a child of another panel. But, I have the solution by doing something like you said.

Comment: @Tunahan - VZ says that each of the panels need to have a different parent. Panel D is a child, AND Panel-I is a child of Panel-D...